# Using MySQL LIKE operator for fields encoded in JSON

Tags: mysql, json

I've been trying to get a table row with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field` LIKE "%\u0435\u0442\u043e\u0442%"
```

Field itself:

```
Field                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------
\u0435\u0442\u043e\u0442 \u0442\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0442 \u043d\u0430
```

Although I can't seem to get it working properly.
I've already tried experimenting with the backslash character:

```
LIKE "%\\u0435\\u0442\\u043e\\u0442%"
LIKE "%\\\\u0435\\\\u0442\\\\u043e\\\\u0442%"
```

But none of them seems to work, as well.

I'd appreciate if someone could give a hint as to what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance!

---

### EDIT

Problem solved.
Solution: even after correcting the syntax of the query, it didn't return any results. After making the field BINARY the query started working.

Comment: If those are escaped Unicode characters, why don't you simply store them unescaped in a Unicode-encoded textual string column?

Comment: As I mentioned in the title, it's actually in JSON format I'm storing the data. So as far I see JSON replaces non-ascii characters with these unicode entities.

Comment: Apologies, I overlooked the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented under [String Comparison Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

> #### Note
>
> Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, “`\n`” to represent a newline character), you must double any “`\`” that you use in [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) strings. For example, to search for “`\n`”, specify it as “`\\n`”. To search for “`\`”, specify it as “`\\\\`”; this is because the backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.

Therefore:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field` LIKE '%\\\\u0435\\\\u0442\\\\u043e\\\\u0442%'
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58b00/1/0).

Comment: I understand that's the correct syntax, although I can't figure out why there's nothing getting returned when I clearly have the row field containing that string.

Comment: @valisj: Well, the sqlfiddle above clearly shows it working... so the problem must lie elsewhere, in something you've not mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

it can be useful for those who use PHP, and it works for me

```
$where[] = 'organizer_info LIKE(CONCAT("%", :organizer, "%"))';
$bind['organizer'] = str_replace('"', '', quotemeta(json_encode($orgNameString)));
```