# JSON_CONTAINS not supported in mysql version 5.1.73

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have some problem to find a record with where clause which the parameters is `JSON` format. For the example the `JSON` column have value like this `["1","2","3"]`. When I run `where JSON_CONTAINS(tags, '["1"]')` it throws an error.

What I want to ask is how to get all record which have value **1** in each `JSON` column ? Maybe I could use `PHP` if there is no way to do that with low version mysql. Please anyone knows to do this could help me. Thank you before.

This is the sample of table record:

```
    id | name    | tags
    ---+---------+------------
    1  | Jason   | ["1","2"]
    2  | Michael | ["4"]
    3  | Sarah   | ["1","3"]
    4  | Lucy    | ["2"]
```

I want to show **Jason** and **Sarah** which have value **1** in tags column.

Comment: I highly suspect that mysql 5.1 has any json support

Comment: @Johnny000 I tried in 5.1 and 5.0 the function not supported.

Comment: It's only available in mysql >= 5.7

Comment: @Johnny000 Yes, it's only available in mysql >= 5.7 so I ask about the another way to achieve that.

Comment: Wow sorry, I misread the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `LIKE` to check if the field contains the result;

```
SELECT * FROM jsondata WHERE tags LIKE '%"1"%'
```

However, [as outlined in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13671191/8991005) you might have to account for escaped characters and encoding when reading JSON in this fashion.

Comment: How if the value contains ["1","51"] it will find just 1 or it will find 51 also ?

Comment: No, it will only find 1 because you have the quotes around the 1.